# Cocos2d - CCLabelTTF overlays new value when updated

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a `CCLabelTTF` variable defined as follows

```
@implementation LevelScene
{
    CCLabelTTF *_collectedLabel;

    int collectedStars1;
    int collectedStars2;
    int collectedStars3;
}
```

I also have a `CCScrollView` and I listen for `scrollViewDidScroll`.

```
- (void)setPageIndicatorTo:(NSInteger)page
{
    if (page == 0) {
        _collectedLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/75", collectedStars1];
    } else if (page == 1) {
        _collectedLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/75", collectedStars2];
    } else if (page == 2) {
        _collectedLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/75", collectedStars3];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(CCScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self setPageIndicatorTo:_scrollView.horizontalPage];
}
```

In `didLoadFromCCB`, I set `_collectedLabel.string` to some value. It gives me the following :

[image]

When the view scroll, it calls `- (void)setPageIndicatorTo:(NSInteger)page` and thus updates the string. I then get

[image]

It should be 0/75. The new label overlays the previous one... How can I force the string to be updated?

---

I tried setting the string to "" before setting it to another value, but it gave the same result..

Comment: are you sure you aren't creating duplicates of the score string somewhere? You can find out if you give each score label a slightly random position or color

Comment: Strangely, you are right.. I am creating a duplicate of the score... I never imagined this could be the cause... -- Turns out I was creating the label inside a loop - doh!